# Access attached code for installed Google Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon, google-apps-script-editor

Basically the question is: Can a user access the installed Add-on's code in any way like e.g we can access through Tools Menu -> Script Editor(on SpreadSheets) while on development & pushed through clasp CLI?

Comment: Don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative. Users who have installed the Add-On do not get to see the Add-On code. If they open a Apps Script editor instance from an editor in which an installed add-on is running, the user will get a blank Apps Script project template to work on, not the Add-On code.

They will however see the names of the functions executed in their Apps Script dashboard.

Comment: Thanks! I have also confirmed that. So there is no other too right? Some API keys are attached to the project & pushed so someone might steal it somehow. that's the only concern.

Comment: Which API keys do you mean?

Comment: Just some client_id & client_secret that are usually required for API calls.

Comment: You should load secret or sensitive stuff from a different file (Library) pretty much like you would do with Environment Variables. and this file is not pushed to public or shared repos. Also if the answer works for you please accept it [see-how-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)